# Data Adaptive technique

Tags: signal-analysis, wavelet, adaptive-algorithms

I am doing data analysis. I used the wavelet transform and now I am trying the Hilbert–Huang transform (HHT). In the literature, I read that Hilbert–Huang transform (HHT) is an adaptive technique. I tried to find how it is adaptive or what is the meaning of adaptive in this context. I didn't get any answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your concern. I am doing analysis and soon I hope I may need your help. I will let you know soon. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to vote but I got this warning:Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hilbert-Huang signal decomposition possesses **a non-adaptive part** (the Hilbert transform) and **an adaptive, or data-driven part**: the decomposition of  a signal as a sum for Intrinsic Mode Functions (IMF), that are obtained by a deflation process, using extrema and envelopes of the signal, recursively.

Thus, IMFs are adaptive with respect to the signal: if you change the value of one sample, the IMFs can be drastically different. For some classes of processes, namely fractional Brownian motions, the 
[Empirical mode decompositions [can act as] as data-driven wavelet-like expansions](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0219691304000561). In other words, **under some conditions, an adaptive algorithm may behave like a non-adaptive one**.

There is one code for [Marginal Hilbert Spectrum](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27531-marginal-hilbert-spectrum) on Matlab Central.

Comment: Thank you so much. Very helpful..